# Getting XML / HTML test results for android gradle junit test run

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, junit

I'm having a hard time finding xml / html test results after running my tests through gradle either with `./gradlew test` or `./gradlew testDebug`. When I run either of those I wind up with an html file that shows 0 tests and no xml file at all.

According to the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line) XML test results should be in `path_to_your_project/module_name/build/test-results/` but the test-results folder only has `.bin` files in it (`results.bin`, etc). I also tried searching with `find app/build -type f -name "*.xml"` but only found Android related XML files (manifest, merge files, etc).

Output from `./gradlew --version`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_212 (Oracle Corporation 25.212-b03)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-50-generic amd64
```

I want to get test results to publish to jenkins. I have the same issue if I run on my local MBP as well. I have not modified any of the gradle test configurations but the link above seems to suggest I shouldn't need to.

I also tried specifying my test directory with

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing this from my `/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      useJUnitPlatform()
    }
  }
}
```

[This guide](https://www.lordcodes.com/posts/testing-on-android-using-junit-5) helped me figure that out

Answer (score -1):

run following command from android studio terminal/or ubuntu machine.

```
gradlew tasks
```

see the list of options available under group test and use for respective flavor.

```
gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

[in my app i am using this command. Output is generated in 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\reports\tests\testDebugUnitTest']

Comment: I still have the same results - just a generated index.html of the results with no tests listed in it